# How to achieve this layout? (image at left and some text at right)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to have a layout with a image at left and at right some text. The text should be with this structure:

```
Item 0: value 0
Item 1: value 1
Item 2: value 2
```

But this text is appearing in only one row like:

Item 0: value 0
Item 1: value 1
Item 2: value 2

Do you know why?

Fiddle with the issue:http://jsfiddle.net/Lwu2zxzd/

Html:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/>
    <p><strong class="text-bg-gray">Item1: </strong>value1</p>
    <p><strong class="text-bg-gray">Item2: </strong>valu2</p>
    <p><strong class="text-bg-gray">Item3: </strong>value3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `p` tags are flex items of the flex container and since you used `flex-row` you will have this output. To fix this, you can imply add another div to wrap the text:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" >
    <div>
      <p class="mb-0"><strong class="text-bg-gray">Item1: </strong>value1</p>
      <p class="mb-0"><strong class="text-bg-gray">Item2: </strong>value2</p>
      <p class="mb-0"><strong class="text-bg-gray">Item3: </strong>value3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```